# Running Microsoft Graph Toolkit for development purposes from github repo causes HTTP 431

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-account, microsoft-graph-toolkit

First I prepared the repo as described in [the contributing guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md) by cloning it, restoring and building it.

When running `yarn start` the app starts on localhost. I sign in using a Microsoft account (no work or school account) and eventually I am presented with HTTP 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large).

There is a header `Cookie` which is 8563 characters long and appears to be an aggregation of several JWTs. It goes like this:

> msal.a974dfa0-9f57-49b9-95db-90f04ce2111a.client.info=eyJ1aWQiOiIwMDAwMDAwMC0wMDAw...; msal.a974dfa0-9f57-49b9-95db-90f04ce2111a.login.request|c8591ba7-8643-4dd0-a86c-38240fd5c6e9=http://localhost:3000/; msal.a974dfa0-9f57-49b9-95db-90f04ce2111a.authority|c8591ba7-8643-4dd0-a86c-38240fd5c6e9=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/; msal.a974dfa0-9f57-49b9-95db-90f04ce2111a.nonce.idtoken|c8591ba7-8643-4dd0-a86c-38240fd5c6e9=950c6017-41e9-4244-a874-02e7d8d40f47; msal.a974dfa0-9f57-49b9-95db-90f04ce2111a.state.acquireToken|c8591ba7-8643-4dd0-a86c-38240fd5c6e9=eyJpZCI6ImM4NTkx...;msal.a974dfa0-9f57-49b9-95db-90f04ce2111a.login.request|965aad0f-7740-44db-8be3-8a21d26c4f2d=http://localhost:3000/; msal.a974dfa0-9f57-49b9-95db-90f04ce2111a.authority|965aad0f-7740-44db-8be3-8a21d26c4f2d=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/; msal.a974dfa0-9f57-49b9-95db-90f04ce2111a.nonce.idtoken|965aad0f-7740-44db-8be3-8a21d26c4f2d=5b3e211d-6756-4892-b50d-17cdebbd18b3; msal.a974dfa0-9f57-49b9-95db-90f04ce2111a.state.acquireToken|965aad0f-7740-44db-8be3-8a21d26c4f2d=eyJpZCI6Ijk2NWFhZDBm

This goes on for quite some time and somewhere in between there is this:

> msal.a974dfa0-9f57-49b9-95db-90f04ce2111a.error.description=Silent authentication was denied. The user must first sign in and if needed grant the client application access to the scope 'user.read people.read user.readbasic.all contacts.read calendars.read presence.read.all tasks.readwrite presence.read user.read.all group.read.all tasks.read openid profile'.;

Of course I have accepted all those permission requests, even revoked them once and regranted to start over clean.

What am I not getting?

I use Win 10, node 12.19.0 and VS Code 1.51.1. and access the provided app (Amazing Microsoft Graph Toolkit App - client ID a974dfa0-9f57-49b9-95db-90f04ce2111a) which is the default in the [index.html](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/blob/main/index.html) file.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: (1) Make sure you're using the latest MSAL, if not try the same and see if you can repro the issue or not. (2) If you're downloaded a sample and trying, i would suggest you to create a new app registration in your own tenant (don't use the pre-configured client id specified in it and tenant info etc), similarly do the changes in your code when needed - this will help you to move forward.

Comment: @Dev thanks for your ideas, but neither helped. Also, I am not trying to develop anything, just to get the samples running and they don't.

Comment: hmm... gotcha.. then i would suggest you to open a new issues at their Github link @ https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues - so that the respective team can help you.